# How to create sale products for specific SKU for Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Just wanted to ask for a way on how to make product sale on a specific SKU with a lot of product combinations. Ex., Product 1 has also 7 product combination but i wanted to sale just 1 item, so 6 other products has the original price but 1 product has sale price in the same group. Please help me with this. I've been searching for a solution for this for a day but not yet found some. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by assigning a "specific price" in the `product > pricing` tab and then choosing the approriate combination from the "Combinations" select field